# Using threads and event handlers within a WCF Web Service

Tags: c#, wcf, multithreading, event-handling

While making a WCF Web Service, I came across a problem while using a method with a webbrowser control. The method starts a thread and uses a webbrowser control to fill in some forms and click further, waiting for a event handler to fire and return a answer I need. The method is tested and works within its own enviroment, but used in a WCF Web Service enviroment, the event handlers just won't fire. A result of that is the waiting manualresetevent not ending. Is this because of the new thread or because of the bad event handling of the web service? If yes, what is a reasonable solution?

Comment: Just to check - the `WebBrowser` is at the *client*, yes?

Comment: A web application uses the web service. The web service needs its own browser-element with event handlers to fill in and get information from another site.

So: Browser1 --> Web App --> Web Service --> do action on other site (new Browser --> open url --> Fill in URL --> press ok --> catch response --> process answer) --> return answer to web service

Comment: You're better off using `HttpWebRequest` or `WebClient`, since they also enable you to do synchronous requests.

Answer (score 0):

> Browser1 --> Web App --> Web Service
>   --> do action on other site (new Browser --> open url --> Fill in URL
>   --> press ok --> catch response --> process answer)

if the part of your system that creates a "new browser" is running as a service, either as a Windows Service, a self-hosted WCF service process, or something inside of IIS; then more than likely you won't get GUI events because there is no GUI.  GUI event handlers, amongst other things, require a Windows Message Pump which is not available in these scenarios.

try hosting your service under say a Windows Forms host to see, I suspect it will work.

If you must have your system under IIS or a Windows Service (non-GUI) then you could always communicate to a surrogate host process which has a message pump where it could do all the browsing stuff for you. once complete your "answer" could be sent back to the web app